# Excel not displaying date as text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I received a excel spreadsheet to complete, and there is a column that is displaying a number formatting instead of a date, I tried changing the individual cell by right clicking and formatting the cell into date format however the cell is still displaying a number value instead of the date. See example below:

**43049  instead of 11/10/2017**

What do I need to do to change the cell to display the date text?

Comment: If the 43049 was entered as text (there will be a small green triangle at the top left corner), then you first need to convert it to a number (quick way is to edit the cell and press enter, bulk conversion would be to copy a blank cell, select the range, paste special and pick 'add')

Comment: theres not a green arrow

Comment: Then I cannot reproduce the issue you are describing. 43049 gets properly formatted to 11/10/2017 on my side.

Comment: Select the data. Choose Data - Text to Columns. In step 3 choose data format date. Maybe additional select the date format now.

Comment: https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/80291-dates-display-as-numbers-even-with-date-format

Comment: so if you double click the cell then hit enter does it recognise the datevalue then? - Could also try another column next to that with `=VALUE(A1)` etc. copied down

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the cell or range
In the pop up click on Format Cells
Under Number on the category sub menu click on date and choose the date type you want

OR

Select the Cell Or Cells
Click On HOME menu Ribbon
Change the formatting from General to Short Date